# Find which script is run when request (GET) is sent to port

Tags: request, get, gradio

I am having a hard time trying to do something very simple. I basically want to send a GET variable via URL `https://localhost:port/?foo=bar` and capture it on the script that handles it.

The problem is that I'm using a [gradio](https://www.gradio.app/) app that wasnt developed by me and I have no idea of whats the part of the code that deals with the requests handling/listening.

Is there a way to find which script is run when a request is sent to a port? I have managed to find the server's PID with `lsof -i -P | grep LISTEN | grep :$PORT` but not the filename that handles it.